# INSERT statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint? I tried to insert data in the table ''customer'' but I always got this error

Tags: sql-server

So I tried to insert data in the ''customer'' table but I always get this certain error (at the bottom).
Can anyone pinpoint if I miss anything or if it's lacking?

```
create table rooms
(
    roomid int identity(1,1) primary key,
    roomNo varchar(250) not null unique,
    roomType varchar(250) not null,
    bed varchar(250) not null,
    price bigint not null,
    booked varchar(50) default 'NO'
);

insert into rooms (roomNo, roomType, bed, price) values (010, 'Studio with AC', 'Single', '1000');

create table customer
(
    cid int identity(1,1) primary key,
    cname varchar(250) not null,
    mobile bigint not null,
    nationality varchar(250) not null,
    gender varchar(50) not null,
    dob varchar(50) not null,
    idproof varchar(50) not null,
    addres varchar(250) not null,
    checkIn varchar(250) not null,
    checkOut varchar(250),
    chekOut varchar(250) not null default 'NO',
    roomid int foreign key references rooms(roomid)
);

insert into customer (cname,mobile,nationality,gender,dob,idproof,addres,checkIn,customer.roomid) values ('Kayano Ai', 09238400394, 'Japanese', 'Female', '01-02-1998', '8923giaf', 'Somewhere', 'YES', 20);
```

the error notif I got is
**The INSERT statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint "FK__customer__roomid__1F98B2C1". The conflict occurred in database "myHotel", table "dbo.rooms", column 'roomid'.**

Comment: And is the foreign key constraint satisfied by having an existing row in `rooms`? Without seeing your insert statement and the contents of your table, how can we solve it?

Comment: A block of code does not define requirements, so we must assume. If your goal is to both insert a row in rooms and then to insert a row into customer using the ID of the previous statement, then you're doing it wrong. Your second insert uses a hardcoded value for roomid - why is that? Think about that for a bit. Do you NOT need to somehow get the identity value generated for the row inserted by the first statement?

Comment: And I'll point out that a customer might rent multiple rooms at a time. A good customer will repeatedly stay at your hotel / facility. Designing databases is a very different skill than writing tsql queries and applications that use a database. Quite frankly, the datatypes you have chosen for your tables are just a mess. As are columns `checkOut` and `chekOut` - no one but you will understand the difference.

Answer (score 0):

When you enter row into your customer table, customer.roomid should exist in the rooms table first.

Fist make sure the room exists or insert a new room.

```
INSERT INTO rooms ( roomid,roomNo, ...) VALUES (1,'room1',...);
```

Then insert into customer with an custormer.roomid that exists in the room table (1 in the example)

```
INSERT INTO customer ( cid,cname,roomid ...) VALUES (15,'customer name',1,...);
```

Comment: But roomid in rooms (not room) is an identity column - your solution breaks at the first statement. Nor does tsql use double characters as a string delimiter.

Comment: Updated the query on your comments